# Issues in while using Redis client for Golang (github.com/go-redis/redis)

Tags: go, redis, open-telemetry

I'm facing to following issues while using **Redis client for Golang** (https://github.com/go-redis/redis). Those issues are related to the movement of **go.opentelemetry.io/otel/api/** form **go.opentelemetry.io/otel**. I would be thankful for anyone to suggest a workaround for these issues.

1. $GOPATH\src\github.com\go-redis\redis\internal\instruments.go:6:2: cannot find package "go.opentelemetry.io/otel/api/global" in any of:
2. $GOPATH\src\github.com\go-redis\redis\internal\instruments.go:7:2: cannot find package "go.opentelemetry.io/otel/api/metric" in any of:
3. $GOPATH\src\github.com\go-redis\redis\internal\util.go:10:2: cannot find package "go.opentelemetry.io/otel/api/trace" in any of:

Since instruments.go and util.go use

- "go.opentelemetry.io/otel/api/global"
- "go.opentelemetry.io/otel/api/metric"
- "go.opentelemetry.io/otel/api/trace"

Comment: Edit the question to show how you go the package. The command `go get github.com/go-redis/redis/v8` works for me.

Comment: I have used "go get github.com/go-redis/redis". Thank you so much for your quick response.

Comment: Follow the [installation instructions](https://github.com/go-redis/redis#installation) for the package.